# facebook integration with .net

Tags: c#

i am working on c#, where in i want to integrate a login button and a like button on my application . from where the user can update his status . can i get that code in c#.

Comment: "can i get that code in c#." - you want fries with that?

Answer (score 4):

First download [Facebook SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/).

And then read their [documentation](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation).